# How to deploy a SenchaTouch App with Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

A friend send me the code of a SenchaTouch App (v2.0) he made. I should make some changes as the performance is not so good. To start, I want to "deploy" the App on my iPad and see where its slow. He told me that he didn't use SenchaCmd and the Cordova version seems a little bit older, too. In the picture below you can see the project structure. How can I deploy the App to my iPad (there are no XCode project files in these folders)? In the future I will do a complete refactoring of the App but for the moment he wants me to do some little performance tweeks with his code... Any suggestions?

[image: project structure]

Comment: To deploy to your iPad you're going to have to have a .xcodeproj file, which is generated by Cordova when you run the command line script. Did he just send you only that folder? You may just need to create a project with Cordova, then drop the contents of that folder into the www directory.

Comment: Yes, he only mailed me the content from the image in a zip file. I'll try to create a new project and hope it works. Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andres commnt was the correct hint. I could just create a new cordova/phonagap project with the command line and then put the contents of the folder in the www directory.